# Presheaves are locally sheaves?

Tags: sheaf-theory

On [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sheafification) it says that a presheaf is locally isomorphic to a sheaf. What do they mean by locally isomorphic? Their definition of locally isomorphic is given in terms of Grothendieck topologies which i think is overkill.

When I first read the nlab page, I thought that it might mean that every presheaf, when restricted to a small enough open set is a sheaf, but I have doubts now because I can't find a proof in the literature and I can't prove it myself.

Comment: Given that they *defined* a sheaf in terms of Grothendieck topologies, its not surprising that their other definitions involve them. If you're not dealing with such things I guess you could drop the *Grothendieck* bit. And the statement that presheaves are locally isomorphic to sheaves is almost tautological, given their definition of local isomorphism = isomorphism after passing to sheaves.

Comment: But, having said that, I don't think this question is really suitable here. Maybe math.stackexchange would be a better place?

Comment: Give a presheaf $F$, any  the section $s\in Sh(F)(U)$  of the  associated sheaf are locally  sections of the presheaf i.e exist a covering $U=\cup_i U_i$ such that any restriction $s_{|U_i}$ come from (by the reflection map $r_{U_i}: F(U_i)\to Sh(F)(U_i)$) a section of the presheaf.   

Comment: The statement in the nLab entry about local isomorphism is correct, with the definition of local isomorphism as given at the page linked to: the canonical morphism from a presheaf to its sheaffification is a morphism that becomes an isomorphism under sheafification. Such morphisms are traditionally called local isomorphisms. And yes, this is a special case of the general theory of left exact reflective localizations.

Comment: Evidently, my previous comment was wrong. Sorry.

Comment: -1: Daniel, did you ever think to look up the page local isomorphism on the nLab: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/local+isomorphism ?  Also, the definition in terms of Grothendieck topologies is a necessary complication of the theory WRT local isomorphisms (or else we're left with only the trivial case).  See my comment on Clark Barwick's answer.

Comment: Dear George, the world would be a much better place if more people were willing to say they had been wrong and apologized. You have all my admiration for your last comment. 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dear Daniel, the reason you couldn't find a proof of your statement nor locate one in the literature is that it is false ; so you were quite right  to "have doubts now" ! Here are two (essentially equivalent) statements that hopefully clarify the situation.

**I) Given a presheaf $\mathcal F$ on a topological space, it is not true that there exists a non-empty open subset $U\subset X$ such that the restriction $\mathcal F |U$ is a sheaf.**

For example take $X=\mathbb R$ and define the presheaf $\mathcal F$ by  $\mathcal F(V)= \mathbb Z$ for all open 
$V\subset \mathbb R$ (constant presheaf on $\mathbb R$ with values in $\mathbb Z$). Since every open $U$ contains disjoint open subsets,
the restriction $\mathcal F |U$ is never a sheaf.

**II) Given a presheaf $\mathcal F$ on a topological space and its sheafification

$\mathcal F \to \mathcal F'$ it is not true that there exists a non-empty open subset $U\subset X$ such that the restricted morphism $\mathcal F |U \to  \mathcal F'|U$ is an isomorphism  of presheaves.**

In the preceding example the sheafification $\mathcal F'$ is the sheaf of *locally* constant $\mathbb Z $-valued functions and again for every $U\subset \mathbb R$ you will find *disjoint* open intervals $I_1,I_2 \subset U$ for which
$\mathcal F(I_1\sqcup I_2)= \mathbb Z \neq \mathcal F'(I_1\sqcup I_2)= \mathbb Z^2$ . So 
the restricted morphism $\mathcal F |U \to  \mathcal F'|U$ is not an isomorphism of presheaves.

**Conclusion** I find it ambiguous, as proved by this very question, to call a morphism of sheaves a "local isomorphism" if it is an isomorphism on the stalks. I don't know how widespread this usage is but in my opinion people using it should warn their readers if they decide to adopt it. On the other hand, I must concede that everybody (myself included) calls $\mathcal F'$ a *constant* sheaf. This terminology also seems a little misleading but it is firmly entranched now and is here to stay.

**An answer to Roy's question**  He asks (in his answer below) for an example of a presheaf all of whose restrictions to open subsets are non-separated. [Recall that a presheaf 
 $\mathcal F$ is said to be separated if  given a covering $U=\cup U_i $ of an open set $U$ by open subsets $U_i$, you can deduce for two sections $f,g\in \mathcal F (U)$ that $f=g$ as soon as you know that $f| U_i=g| U_i$  for all $i$ . This is equivalent to saying that, if  $\mathcal F'$ denotes the sheafification of $\mathcal F$, all morphisms 
$\mathcal F (U) \to \mathcal F'(U)$  are injective.]

Here is the example. On the topological space $\mathbb R$ consider the sheaf of continuous functions $\mathcal C$, its subpresheaf $\mathcal C_b $ of continuous *bounded* functions ( Caution: this is *not* a sheaf !) and the quotient presheaf 
$\mathcal F=  \mathcal C / \mathcal C_b  $ i.e. for $V$ open in $\mathbb R$, $\mathcal F(V)=\mathcal C (V)/ \mathcal C_b (V)  $. It is then clear that for all non-empty open $V\subset \mathbb R$ we have $\mathcal F(V) \neq 0$ but for the sheafification $\mathcal F'$ we have $\mathcal F'(V)= 0$  (because every continuous function is *locally* bounded !). And this is the example requested by Roy: for every non-empty $U$ the restriction $\mathcal F |U $ is a non-separated presheaf on $U$ : $\mathcal F |U \neq 0$ certainly does not inject into $\mathcal F'|U =0$

Comment: An isomorphism on the level of stalks should probably be called an "infinitesimal isomorphism."

Comment: That's not why it's called a local isomorphism.  It's called a local isomorphism because it becomes an isomorphism of "local objects".  This is pretty standard terminology from as far back as Gabriel-Zisman.  

Comment: Also, Georges, I find it natural to require two objects to be globally morphic before we can talk about whether or not they're locally isomorphic. The OP's condition regarding restriction sheaves should instead be called "local satisfaction of the sheaf conditions".  For instance, we say two manifolds are locally diffeomorphic if there exists a morphism admitting sections locally about each point.

Comment: Harry, all manifolds of the same dimension are locally diffeomorphic, independently of any morphisms betwen them. On the other hand a submersion of a manifold onto another one of lower dimension has local sections about each point but the manifolds are certainly not locally diffeomorphic. Finally I have never heard the notion of objects being globally morphic .

Comment: Dear Georges, two manifolds are locally diffeomorphic iff there exists a local diffeomorphism from one to the other (whence globally morphic).

Comment: Dear Harry, since our discussion hinges on terminology, I have nothing  to add: we just seem to have different definitions. Thank you for your interest in this post and for sharing  your point of view.

Comment: @Harry: it seems that your view on what "local isomorphism" means keeps coming up and it seems that no one else thinks that it should mean what you are suggesting. Requiring the existence of a morphism for saying that two objects are "locally isomorphic" is an overkill. In particular, in most cases, this will imply that those objects are actually *isomorphic*. Think of sheaves; if there is a morphism $\mathcal F\to \mathcal G$ that's an isomorphism on the stalks, then it is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Georges: Just a comment on your sentence "*I find it ambiguous, as proved by this very question, to call a morphism of sheaves a "local isomorphism" if it is an isomorphism on the stalks.*": Actually, it is not at all ambiguous, but there are different issues here: First of all, if you have a morphism of sheaves which is an isomorphism on stalks, then it is an isomorphism (don't need the "local"!). I think what you may have had in mind is to say that: *Two sheaves are locally isomorphic if their stalks are isomorphic*.This might seem ambiguous in light of your example, but it is not! (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd from above) The point is that in your example the objects are not *sheaves* but pre-sheaves. So, it is perfectly all right to say that "Two sheaves are locally isomorphic if their stalks are isomorphic" because it is equivalent to saying that the ambient space has an open cover such that for any of the open sets in this cover the restrictions of the two sheaves are isomorphic. In some sense, this is the point of studying sheaves, instead of pre-sheaves, they can be re-built from their stalks, or one could say they are *locally determined*.

Comment: p.s.: I am sure I am not saying anything new to you. :)


Comment: p.p.s: And I agree that it is ambiguous to say that *a presheaf is locally isomorphic to a sheaf* but I don't think this is widely used.

Comment: Dear Sándor, I agree with everything you say and I am sure we are in complete agreement on everything concerning the mathematical substance of (pre)sheaves. And, yes, my sentence on ambiguity was probably ambiguous! It's just that sheaves are pretty subtle the first time you meet them :  all vector bundles give rise to sheaves that are locally but not globally isomorphic, etc.  (to be continued)

Comment: (continuation) So I feel we should help beginners in that field by not only telling them what is true but also by drawing their attention to potential misconceptions and (this is more subjective) ambiguities. Anyway, thanks a lot for your expert and relevant comments.

Comment: Dear Georges, I totally agree and my comment was more to those who read yours than to you. (See p.p.s above). What I meant to point out is that for sheaves this is not an issue = yet another reason why sheaves are good and presheaves are less so. 

Answer (score 18):

Here's one way to answer your question. Consider the category $\mathbf{PSh}(X)$ of presheaves (of sets) on a topological space $X$. A map $F\to G$ of $\mathbf{PSh}(X)$ is said to be a *local isomorphism* if for every point $x\in X$, the induced map $F_x\to G_x$ on stalks is a bijection. Denote by $W$ the class of local isomorphisms. Now the category $\mathbf{Sh}(X)$ of *sheaves* on $X$ is equivalent to the localization $W^{-1}\mathbf{PSh}(X)$. In particular, for any presheaf $F$, there is a local isomorphism $F\to F'$, where $F'$ is a sheaf.

Comment: @Daniel: Clark's answer extends to the general case  of an arbitrary base category with grothendieck topology $\tau$ by defining $W_\tau$ to be $Sh_\tau^{-1}(Iso(Psh(C))$.  The rather more interesting part of this question, however, is that there exists a direct characterization of these "systems of local isomorphisms".  It is then a theorem that Grothendieck topoogies on $C$ are in canonical bijection with systems of local isomorphisms on $Psh(C)$.  

Answer (score 4):

Arrgh, I wish to delete this, but do not know how.  So i will make it into a question.  Georges' nice answer is a presheaf that violates the existence axiom s2 on every nbhd of a point.  Is there an example that violates the uniqueness axiom s1 on every nbhd of some point?

Comment: Dear Roy, I have answered your interesting question in an addendum to my original answer. Please do not delete your question above, else readers will be disoriented by my orphaned answer!

Comment: Thank you Georges!  If I understand correctly, in your example every element becomes zero near the point, but there is no set on which all do at once.  It seems so clear after seeing it.  I.e. this is all that is needed to make all the stalks zero, which makes the sheaf (but not the presheaf) zero.